# Creating new object instance still has old data in it

Tags: python

I have a file that runs some analysis on an object I pass to it

something like this:

`test.py`:

```
class Test:
    var_array = []

    def add_var(self, new_var):
        self.var_array.append(new_var)

def run(test):
    for var in test.var_array:
        print var
```

I have another file where I define the information I want processed

`test2.py`:

```
import os
import sys

TEST_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

if TEST_DIR not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(TEST_DIR)
from test import *

test = Test()
test.add_var('foo')
run(test)
```

so if I run this multiple times

```
In [1]: %run test2.py
foo

In [2]: %run test2.py
foo
foo

In [3]: %run test2.py
foo
foo
foo
```

What am I doing wrong? Shouldn't `test = Test()` create a new instance of the object?

Comment: Surely `if TEST_DIR in sys.path` should be `if TEST_DIR not in sys.path`...

Comment: @kindall right. Just a typo, fixed now.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the following code `var_array` is class variable (which is shared by all instance of `Test` objects):

```
class Test:
    var_array = []
```

To define instance variable, you should initialize it in the `__init__` method as follow:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var_array = []
```